How to find current direction from voltage value?
+2024.06.04. editted
I'm adding an example image of the data I have.
My circuit is a raster(matrix) format, and each cell (entry) is a node of the circuit. In the example, 1A is injected into the current source. Please refer to the image for the current and voltage values if you need. If -1A is assigned to the source in the same circuit, the voltage value is negative. And there are only source, ground and resistor in this circuit.
Actually, my ultimate goal is to express the direction of current flow in the node of the circuit in radians. I tried to get help from Claude AI, but since I don't have knowledge about circuits, the arrow of the result pointed in the wrong direction..:(
If you can tell me the formula, theory, or code that can solve this problem, it will be a great joy and help to me.


I am a researcher in a different field. My research requires calculations based on circuit theory.
Is it possible to find the direction of the current using only the voltage and current values of each node in the circuit? I only have the voltage value and current value data of each node. Current data has no information about direction. But I need to know the direction in which the current flows. Additional data that may be helpful includes the location of the current source and ground.
If I can find the direction of the current using only these data, please tell me how. Thank you

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

what do you mean by "current value at each node". ?


How to find current direction from voltage value?

From the voltage values alone, no, not in every circuit.
If your circuit contains only linear resistive elements or is operating in DC steady state conditions, then it is possible.
If your circuit contains nonlinear resistors (for example, diodes) or active elements (for example, transistors), then it might be possible, but it is also possible to design circuits that have hysteretic behavior, so that some of the branch currents depend on the history of the evolution of the node voltages and not just their state at one point in time.
If your circuit contains inductors and isn't in a DC steady state condition, then it isn't possible. You'd have to know the history of the voltage values to know the currents through the inductors. (Hysteretic behavior is also common in inductors)
If your circuit contains capacitors and isn't in a DC steady state condition, you'd need to know the rate of change of the node voltages to know the currents through the capacitors.

Is it possible to find the direction of the current using only the voltage and current values of each node in the circuit?

About the "current values" for the nodes, KCL (Kirchhoff's Current Law) tells us the total current into any node from all the branches connected to it is zero. So the "current value" for any node at any time is 0.
If you meant to say you know the current of every branch in the circuit, then yes this is enough to know the current in every branch in the circuit because you've assumed you know the information you're asking whether you can determine.
If you know the current magnitude for every branch but not the direction, it's very likely you could work out the directions by observation of the circuit and finding which combinations of directions for the different branches lead to the sums for each node coming to 0.
But I don't know off the top of my head if you can prove that this is always possible for any circuit.

Conventional current flows from higher voltage to lower voltage, so comparing the voltage at various stops along a circuit measured from a common reference (ground, the negative terminal of the power supply etc.) will tell you the direction of current flow through each branch of the circuit. If all the voltage values you have are measured from the same common ground, simply compare the voltage values between two locations and that will tell you the direction of the current flow.

RE: "Conventional current flows from higher voltage to lower voltage" this is only true in a limited set of circumstances. It isn't true in the power sources of the circuit. It isn't true in the inductor in a boost converter during part of the switching cycle. It isn't true in a discharging capacitor.  Without knowing that OP's circuit is, for example, composed of only resistors, we shouldn't make this blanket statement.

In a circuit that includes a rechargeable battery, the direction of current through the battery depends on whether the battery is charging or discharging, but the direction of the voltage between the battery terminals does not ever change.
